# Data about countries and how they are divided into regions/countries/states/etc?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, county

Where can I find a list of all the countries and how they are divided into regions/counties/states/etc? For instance, in India it's states, in Russia it's krai/oblast', in Thailand it's provinces, in Mexico it's states, in Norway counties. In some countries there's no such a division at all.

I want **"country: [names of the divisions]"** data. Not merely the name of the division -- state, oblast', province, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[Population statistics](http://citypopulation.de/) is an excellent resource for such data.

> Population Statistics for Countries, Administrative Areas, Cities and Agglomerations – Interactive Maps and Charts